# Can someone please help me with this Java manipulation code. I wanna know how come the last two printouts are 35 respectively instead of 8?

Tags: java

This is how code looks like:
The first printout is 8 which is correct but the 2nd and 3rd printouts are 35 respectively, how?

```
    int x = 3;
    int y = 5;
    String s6 = x + y + "total";
    String s7 = "total " + x + y;
    String s8 = " " + x + y + "total";
    System.out.println("s6: " + s6);
    System.out.println("s7: " + s7);
    System.out.println("s8: " + s8);
```

Comment: The `+` operator is left-associative, so it evaluates from left to right. It's performing string concatenation.

Comment: Because in s6 it is 3+5+total from left to right so 8total but in s7 first total and 3 is added which makes it total3 and then 5 so total35. This is called operator precedence